# Speech recognizer Intent not closed in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, google-speech-api

I am a beginner in Android. In my program, the speech recognizer Intent not getting closed if no speech detected. Please find the below code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Please respond...");
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 100);
    startActivityForResult(intent, SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Please send your valuable suggestions to close the Google speech recognizer prompt.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find any thing?

Answer (score 0):

Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, new Long(2000));

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but same problem persist. I am trying with finish()

Answer (score 0):

You have to use timer , Use this code to get back to the activity & closing Intent. This time is set to 5000Mili-Seconds , you can change as per your need.

```
 new java.util.Timer().schedule(
                new java.util.TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        finishActivity(request_code);
                    }
                },
                5000
        );
```